# The access token has expired and could not be refreshed. Errors: refresh error, refresh error, refresh error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-oauth

I'm integrate google calendar api in aps.net mvc application .
I get error "The access token has expired and could not be refreshed. Errors: refresh error, refresh error, refresh error".
the code work correctly when run it on localhost but when I run it on server I have the above error
the code is

```
public async Task< ActionResult> Index()
    {
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var _User = "Usr" + userId;
            string credPath = Server.MapPath($"~/UsersToken/{_User}");
            UserCredential UsrCred = null;
            FileDataStore fileStore = new FileDataStore(credPath);
            TokenResponse tokenResponse = await fileStore.GetAsync<TokenResponse>(userId);

            if (!Directory.Exists(credPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(credPath);
            }
            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(credPath);
            DirectorySecurity security = info.GetAccessControl();
            security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Users", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
            info.SetAccessControl(security);

            if (tokenResponse == null)
            {
                var result = new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).AuthorizeAsync(CancellationToken.None);
                if (result.Result.Credential == null) // <<- it's always true, so it always gets redirected
                    return Redirect(result.Result.RedirectUri);
                else
                {
                    UsrCred = result.Result.Credential;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                    new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                    {
                        ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                        {
                            ClientId = _clientId,
                            ClientSecret = _clientSecret
                        },
                        Scopes = Scopes,
                        DataStore = new FileDataStore(credPath, true)
                    //DataStore = new FileDataStore(Google.Apis.Auth)
                });
                UsrCred = new UserCredential(flow, userId, tokenResponse);
            }

            // Create Google Calendar API service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = UsrCred,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });
            // Define parameters of request.
            EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
            request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
            request.ShowDeleted = false;
            request.SingleEvents = true;
            request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;
            Events events = request.Execute();

            List<EventModel> Result = new List<EventModel>();
            if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
                {
                    Result.Add(
                        new EventModel()
                        {
                            Sumarry = eventItem.Summary,
                            Description = eventItem.Description,
                            StartDate = eventItem.Start.DateTime,
                            EndDate = eventItem.End.DateTime,
                            GoogleMeetLink = eventItem.HangoutLink
                        }
                     );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("No upcoming events found.");
            }

            return View(Result);
    }
```

the redirect_url method is

```
public async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsyc(string state, string code, string scope)
    {
        string Lang = ViewBag.Lang ?? "ar";
        string RedirectURL = HttpContext.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + $"/{Lang}/Meetings/IndexAsyc";
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var _User = "Usr" + userId;
        string credPath = Server.MapPath($"~/UsersToken/{_User}");
        UserCredential UsrCred = null;

        FileDataStore fileStore = new FileDataStore(credPath);
        TokenResponse tokenResponse = await fileStore.GetAsync<TokenResponse>(userId);
        // create authorization code flow with clientSecrets
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow authorizationCodeFlow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
        {
            DataStore = new FileDataStore(credPath),
            ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets()
            {
                ClientId = _clientId,
                ClientSecret = _clientSecret
            },
            Scopes = Scopes
        });
        //var result = new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).AuthorizeAsync(CancellationToken.None);

        if (tokenResponse == null)
        {
            // token data does not exist for this user
            tokenResponse = await authorizationCodeFlow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync(
              userId, // user for tracking the userId on our backend system
              code,
              RedirectURL, // redirect_uri can not be empty. Must be one of the redirects url listed in your project in the api console
              CancellationToken.None);
        }
        TokenResponse tokenResponse2 = await fileStore.GetAsync<TokenResponse>(userId);

        if (tokenResponse2 != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        var Creds = new UserCredential(authorizationCodeFlow, userId, tokenResponse2);
        if (Creds != null) // result.Credential != null )
        {
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = Creds,//result.Credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return new RedirectResult(RedirectURL);
        }
    }
```

how can I set token not expire never ?

Comment: Which line number is giving error

Comment: error occour on server not local

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: The access token has expired and could not be refreshed. Errors: refresh error, refresh error, refresh error